# constructor function and new object in javascript / typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I have a task to make a constructor function to make a `Circle` object what calculates area and perimeter.

So far I got the code below and don't understand why `this` is underlined and why `new Circle(3)` is underlined.

I have tried to change `function Circle(this:any, radius: number) {`  to remove underlined `this` but I don't understand why then underlined `new Circle` doesn't fix.

```
function Circle(radius: number) {
    const pi = 3.14;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.area = function () {
        return pi * radius * radius
    }
    this.perimeter = function () {
        return 2 * pi * radius;
    }
}
// pi * r kv
//2pi*r
const c = new Circle(3);
console.log("Area =", c.area().toFixed(2)); // Expected output: Area = 28.27
console.log("Perimeter =", c.perimeter().toFixed(2)); // Expected output: Perimeter = 18.85
```

Comment: Why are you not using Classes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: I thought about using classes, but my excercise is to make this function.

Comment: Your exercise is to make a non-`class` constructor function in a .ts file?  Really?

Comment: Why not? Should I feel pranked now? :)

Comment: It's explicitly not supported, see [microsoft/TypeScript#2310](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310).  All the ways to do it will involve type assertions (i.e., tell the compiler to stop complaining) and you therefore give up type safety.  I mean, it's doable, but... it's a weird ask.  Like someone asking how to open a can of soup with a steak knife when there's a can opener right next to them.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is in a TypeScript file (and not a [JavaScript file checked with TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html)), then this is explicitly not supported, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#2310](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310).  If you want a class constructor in TypeScript, it is strongly recommended that you use `class` syntax.  It will be downleveled to a `function` if the `--target` is ES5 or below, so you don't have to worry about that.  If you use `class` syntax, the `this` context and `new` will just work:

```
class Circle {

  radius: number;
  area: () => number;
  perimeter: () => number;

  constructor(radius: number) {
    const pi = 3.14;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.area = function () {
      return pi * radius * radius
    }
    this.perimeter = function () {
      return 2 * pi * radius;
    }
  }

}

const c = new Circle(3); // okay
```

(Normally I'd expect methods to be on the prototype and not on the instance, but I mostly left your implementation alone).

---

If you really need to support functions as constructors in TypeScript, you'll have to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing:

```
interface Circle {
  radius: number;
  area: () => number;
  perimeter: () => number;
}

interface CircleConstructor {
  new(radius: number): Circle;
}

const Circle = function Circle(this: Circle, radius: number) {
  const pi = 3.14;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.area = function () {
    return pi * radius * radius
  }
  this.perimeter = function () {
    return 2 * pi * radius;
  }
} as any as CircleConstructor;
    
const c = new Circle(3); // okay
```

In the above I've explicitly defined interfaces for both the `Circle` instance type and the `CircleConstructor` constructor type: these happen automatically for you if you use `class` syntax, where the types would be named `Circle` and `typeof Circle` respectively.  Then the `Circle` function needs to be asserted to be of the type `CircleConstructor` in order for the `new Circle(3)` call to work.  Additionally, I gave the function signature a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters), which doesn't exist at runtime but serves to tell the compiler what type it should consider `this` inside the implementation.  I said `this: Circle` to let the compiler know that inside the `Circle` function, it could access `this` properties as if `this` is a `Circle` instance.

So this works more or less the same as the `class` version, except you have to jump through unnecessary hoops to do it, and it's less type safe to boot.  So unless you're doing this for some kind of magic trick (watch me get out of this sealed crate using only a toothpick) I'd strongly recommend that you use `class` syntax, and push back on anyone who asks you to do otherwise in TypeScript.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgMIYhRQDKAnsAC4gAee+hRS81tSCgEsATn2QFuPJCJAATIQFcoALmKKwAIwgiA3FJ4gREEGoAUASiQBeAHzqtO-dKIwdQyMx3mrdh9r0uF14Ae2AoZhFFeGYQkTNZBWU1YA0AqwJgongwiKQYIRskAGYAOgBGABZnLOYACyEoUsSlKCKW5Rrg+sbSoxMigDNFYBihMKRLTiyeY2ZFEWB8woAqGXlWpDWOqANpAF89nh6mtxEPCC8RIZGxianMmZlLhaWAJi3lz52ul0Pgw4GQHSHLhZi8IrACAAd0EonEZmKFl0SAA9KikCEANYgBgGUFQEIYCClDAhADmZgARABBYwgGxUgA0vD69MspViADEhGwIHIzG8LMikPjckSSWTKVSAAruTw6Rks+ClM4XK4c7m8-mC4Uorjcf7EcDQOCIJBc27McbARgsdicAxCFg6QbkOFiYnTFw7FJpJxHfqmSa+eypRyBYJqhUiHw2MP+yM8YE8Z1XN3m4SeiAUXKRaKxa6PaRQ6EJDbJfw6CxqLPiX4p7J5j3iG6ja0TOvEswnWvw4ks31VkQZI4E8EFIplKq-IgnZoVtrWdZJKCzpDzoNtu5LB5HIhzV5fbaL76Lo5G6Tz6OXRXL4btm0h73BQ+LJAfNaTk+r9eXpD7EgNBAcADBAW0XY5nmUQxHE+hBDw44QsupYtt2SK-ASEqkhS1J0gM1jMqyQaaiEPJ8gKQoiuiSAAKJsG4MT8piijMDArFqPhDLLm8AAcpRvAA7GK4TYVK1JyucMZKqyN4ahYnJkdqlF6miGL0YxXhyCxbEcUgknqgaRCAvg+xAA)

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand what you need.
You can use `Class` instead of using a `Function`.
Here is the simple solution which you wanted.

```
class Circle { 
   radius:number; 
   pi = 3.14;
   constructor(radius:number) { 
      this.radius = radius;
   }  

   area():number { 
      return this.pi * this.radius * this.radius;
   } 
   perimeter():number { 
      return 2 * this.pi * this.radius;
   } 
}

var c = new Circle(3);
console.log('Area = '+c.area().toFixed(2));
console.log('Area = '+c.perimeter().toFixed(2));
```

It won't throw any error and follows every standard procedures.
Good luck.