# How to write typescript with constructor function/new keyword?

Tags: javascript, typescript, new-operator

This is an example from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) for the usage of *`new`* keyword

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

const car1 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993);
```

I believe, the TS version of the function would be:

```
/* car type */
type CarDetails = {
    make: string;
    model: string;
    year: number;
}

/* setting this to type CarDetails */
function Car(this:CarDetails, make: string, model:string, year:number) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}
```

This gives me intellisense/autocomplete while writing the method but how do I make TS infer types while creating an instance with `new` keyword. Even after *typescripting* the method, creating an instance like this:

```
const car1 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993);
```

still keeps `car1` as type `any`

#### How to make `car1`'s type infer to be `Car` method's `this` type ?

(without explicitly setting type for the instance object, const `car1: CarDetails = new Car(...;` )

Comment: Why do you want to use a constructor function over `class` here?

Comment: Less lines of code, probably.

Comment: You must be getting a 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type. error.. Don't you ??

Comment: Great, you've saved up on *so much work* that you need help with adding more to your code in order to get it to behave as you want... Doesn't it seem like your approach while *maybe* shorter actually takes more time and effort to do? Also the *maybe* is a big one: https://tsplay.dev/WkMX2N your approach is of comparable length to a normal class. But the class can be shorter.

Comment: @NalinRanjan - No I don't

Comment: strange, because I do in the playground.

Comment: @VLAZ - My use case is different, I re-use type `CarDetails` multiple times through out my code base. I appreciate, you took time for the TS Playground. But if you know the answer, would be nice if you post it.

Comment: But strange.. Is it just me?? `const car1 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993);` does give me ... 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type. error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623461/new-expression-whose-target-lacks-a-construct-signature-in-typescript)

Comment: @NalinRanjan - You are right, it does give an error on Playground, but doesn't show any error on VSCode. Am I missing something in my TS config?

Comment: @Eldar It definitely provides more info about the problem but doesn't answer my question. I just want to know, whether it's possible for the `instance` to infer type from the constructor method's `this`

Comment: "*I re-use type CarDetails multiple times through out my code base.*" which you can also do with a class. Again, I don't understand what you're asking. What is the exact issue you face. Seems you're settled on a Y for [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you keep describing it to me. So, I am unable to understand why you chose it when it's less convenient and more work than an easy alternative. But you never actually describe your requirements for X, just what Y gives you. And only after I specifically point more useful alternatives.

Comment: @saibbyweb `noImplicitAny` is the culprit... Thanks @Eldar

Comment: But I think idiomatic will be to use classes and interfaces while using `new` keyword for constructing objects..

Comment: @VLAZ - Relax. I am just new to TS, just curious what would be the TS equivalent of the example provided in the MDN docs.

Comment: @NalinRanjan - Totally understood. But is it even possible in TS? That's what my question is? Because if it exists, it will save me a lot of time.

Comment: @saibbyweb a class

Comment: @VLAZ - So basically there's no way of making the instance infer the type of construction function's `this`?  That's exactly what I was asking. You can post it as answer, might help future developers.

Comment: Also, if anybody can `list` or direct me to some resource on the internet where I can find similar examples of different JS approaches, whose TS equivalent is a totally different thing. Would highly appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the class syntax should be the way to go, but as you I'm also running in circles trying to find the right solution that outputs the old valid JS syntax. This is a good approximation that [I've found in this random answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66199410/1604261) and it's poorly explained in the [official Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures). Here is the relevant part that I've modified to make it better:

```js
// Only instance members here.
export interface Circle { // Name the interface with the same than the var.
  radius: number;
  area: () => number;
  perimeter: () => number;
}

// You could define static members here.
interface CircleConstructor {
  new(radius: number): Circle;
}

export const Circle = function(this: Circle, radius: number) {
  const pi = 3.14;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.area = function () {
    return pi * radius * radius
  }
  this.perimeter = function () {
    return 2 * pi * radius;
  }
} as unknown /*as any*/ as CircleConstructor; // Note the trust-me casting
    
const c = new Circle(3); // okay
```

This comes with some issues. For instance, the fact that it's using `any` type which is *forbidden* or the necessary use of the `as` operator which is mega-ugly. As improvement, I've used `unknown` instead of `any` but the core problem remains. This makes the lint tool to not complain, so it's a big improvement over the `any`.

This is the best solution I've found so far. Typescript devs are aware of this, but they have decided to not provide support for this kind of "syntax".

Answer (score 0):

You could use classes instead:

```js
class Car {

  make: string;
  model: string;
  year: number;
  
  constructor(make: string, model: string, year: number) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
  }
}

// usage is the same

const car1 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993);
```

Comment: I understand it can be done using a class. But my question is specifically for constructor functions.